# Unsure of how to use LINQ to access this particular element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

*** I'm completely new to this, and this is a personal project I am doing. ***

So I have an XML document structured like this

```
<Licensing key="20325">
  <Organization Org="500">
    <Constraints>
      <MaximumOrgsInSecurity>2</MaximumOrgsInSecurity>
      <MaximumUsersInSecurity>999</MaximumUsersInSecurity>
      <MaximumLoggedInUsers>999</MaximumLoggedInUsers>
      <MaximumLenders>1</MaximumLenders>
      <OptOutofPasswordPolicy>FALSE</OptOutofPasswordPolicy>
    </Constraints>
    <Modules>
      <Module registered="true" name="DV" id="1" />
      <Module registered="true" name="DP" id="2" />
      <Module registered="true" name="DCC" id="3" />
      <Module registered="false" name="DRE" id="4" />
    </Modules>
  </Organization>
</Licensing>
```

and I am trying to read it using LINQ in my C# code, and although I am attempting to following this tutorial on LINQ (http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/564/linq-to-xml-tutorials-examples), I just can't seem to access the elements I would like. For example, how would I use LINQ to get the key number of 20325, Org number of 500, id/name/registered of each module, and stuff like that? The XML document has to be in this format. Any help or walkthroughs would be appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:
          For example, I've tried doing

```
  IEnumerable<XElement> Licensing = xelement.Elements();
  foreach (var Organization in Licensing)
  {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(Organization.Element("Constraints").Value);
  }
```

to see what this would give me, and it gives 29999991FALSE, when I was hoping it would give something along the lines of

```
 MaximumOrgsInSecurity
 MaximumUsersInSecurity
 MaximumLoggedInUsers
 MaximumLenders
 OptOutofPasswordPolicy
```

or at least

```
 2
 999
 999
 1
 False
```

I've also tried doing

```
  IEnumerable<XElement> Licensing = xelement.Elements();
  foreach (var Organization in Licensing)
  {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(Organization.Element("Modules").Value);
  }
```

to see what this would give, and it gives absolutely nothing.

If there is a better way than LINQ to do this, then I am all ears. The only reason I am saying LINQ is because based on what I've found so far, LINQ would be my best bet to achieve what I am attempting to do.

Comment: This isn't a tutorial site. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You said you've attempted to do it and its not working - are you getting nothing? an exception? Compilation errors? If you don't tell us exactly where you are having problems we can't help you learn!

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what to even try when it comes to accessing the key or OrgID number, which is why I am coming for help. My searches on Google for websites that explain how to do that have been rather fruitless.

Comment: @JDawg848 - is this the entire document or are there many sets of 'Licensing' in a container not shown?

Answer (score 1):

Those key values are called Attributes and here's a few different ways to access them:

```
Debug.WriteLine(xelement.Attribute("key").Value);

Debug.WriteLine(xelement.Element("Organization").Attribute("Org").Value);
Debug.WriteLine(((XElement)xelement.FirstNode).Attribute("Org").Value);
```

For the constraints you're selecting a level to high, need to select the child nodes with `.Elements()`:

```
foreach (var constraint in xelement.Descendants("Constraints").Elements())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(constraint.Name + ": " + constraint.Value);
}

foreach (var constraint in xelement.Element("Organization").Element("Constraints").Elements())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(constraint.Name + ": " + constraint.Value);
}
```

You can also add `using System.Diagnostics;` to the top of the file so you don't need to add it before every Debug too.

Answer (score 0):

So based on what @mattmanser said, and further looking into LINQ and Xelement/Xdocument, I figured out how to do what I'm looking to do.

For example, say I want to know all of the "registered" booleans within the modules element and store them in an array of booleans, Id do this:

```
 string Name = FileUpload1.FileName;
 bool[] ModuleBools = new bool[4];

 for (int moduleID = 1; moduleID < 5; moduleID++)
 {
     var quotes = XDocument.Load("C:/Users/.../Created XMLs/" + Name)
                                      .Descendants("Module")
                                      .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == moduleID.ToString())
                                      .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("registered"))
                                      .ToList();

     ModuleBools[moduleID-1] = bool.Parse(quotes.First());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse the VB.  With the given example, here is how you would access each item.  The variable names, though the same as the elements, are just names.

```
    Dim someXE As XElement

    ' someXE = XElement.Load("path here") 'to load from file / uri
    ' for testing we can do this
    someXE = <Licensing key="20325">
                 <Organization Org="500">
                     <Constraints>
                         <MaximumOrgsInSecurity>2</MaximumOrgsInSecurity>
                         <MaximumUsersInSecurity>999</MaximumUsersInSecurity>
                         <MaximumLoggedInUsers>999</MaximumLoggedInUsers>
                         <MaximumLenders>1</MaximumLenders>
                         <OptOutofPasswordPolicy>FALSE</OptOutofPasswordPolicy>
                     </Constraints>
                     <Modules>
                         <Module registered="true" name="DV" id="1"/>
                         <Module registered="true" name="DP" id="2"/>
                         <Module registered="true" name="DCC" id="3"/>
                         <Module registered="false" name="DRE" id="4"/>
                     </Modules>
                 </Organization>
             </Licensing>

    Dim key As String = someXE.@key
    Dim MaximumOrgsInSecurity As String = someXE.<Organization>.<Constraints>.<MaximumOrgsInSecurity>.Value
    Dim MaximumUsersInSecurity As String = someXE.<Organization>.<Constraints>.<MaximumOrgsInSecurity>.Value
    Dim MaximumLoggedInUsers As String = someXE.<Organization>.<Constraints>.<MaximumLoggedInUsers>.Value
    Dim MaximumLenders As String = someXE.<Organization>.<Constraints>.<MaximumLenders>.Value
    Dim OptOutofPasswordPolicy As String = someXE.<Organization>.<Constraints>.<OptOutofPasswordPolicy>.Value
```